# Typescript - return type that is part of whole interface (check if it implements other interface)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a generic reducer that's return type is TableState.

```
const reducerFactory = ..... = (): TableState => ....
```

TableState:

```
 interface TableState {
  filters: Filter;
  data: TableData;
  isLoading: boolean;
}
```

Each component's that uses this reducer factory **implements** TableState.
For example

```
interface SalesReportState implements TableState {
  someCommonField: string;
}
```

App build fails as the types don't match. I could do `someCommonField?: string;` but someCommonField should be obligatory.

Is there a Typescript feature that the return type just **checks** if the table type implements Table State? So the return type would be some type that makes sure it is an instance of TableState, not exactly TableState type.

Comment: Cam you write some more details. TableState  doesnt say me much. Can you show this interface and how you want to use it?

Comment: @MaciejSikora edited, should be better now

Comment: Can you paste the error

Comment: TypeScript error: someCommonField is missing in TableState

Comment: Are u using `SalesReportState ` as `TableState ` ? If so every time you do that you need to use some type guard to narrow the type. You cannot use `TableState ` as more specific `SalesReportState `

Comment: Show me the code of reducer and I will craft you an answer

Comment: Show me the code of reducer and I will craft you an answer

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know if an object implements `TableState`, you can use:

1. <strike>instanceof</strike>

```js
if (obj instanceof TableState) // returns true if object implements TableState
```

only works with abstract class

2. [type-guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types). Example:

```
let obj = {}; // an object you want to check

/**
  * A discriminator is a property which determines if the object in question is
  * a TableState 
  */

function isTableState(obj: any): obj is TableState {
  return obj &&
    obj.filter &&
    obj.data &&
    obj.isLoading && typeof(obj.isLoading) === 'boolean';
}

// check phase
if (isTableState(obj)) {
  // object is automatically casted to TableState
}
```

PS: If you want to extend an interface with another interface, use `extends`
EDIT: I don't know the `Filter` and `TableData` type, is that an interface or a class? The answer may change again, depending on the type

Comment: but what if I want to use it as a return type of a function? `const func = ():TableState => ....` but instead of `TableState` I want to have it there some type that just makes sure it implements TableState.

Comment: instanceof doesn't work for interfaces since interfaces have no runtime representation. They get erased during compilation.

Comment: @IngoBürk Completely slipped my mind about that. Thank you! Revised my answer